# gnu makefile: generating .zip with a subfolder

Tags: makefile, zip, gnu, subdirectory

I have a makefile which gets the content from a folder and saves it on a .zip file. Pretty darn good! The problem is, I want this content to be in a subfolder instead of the root folder of the zip file.

Today: file.zip/content
I want: file.zip/fubfolder/content

This is a piece of my code:

```
buildall: $(BUILDDIR)/index.html \
    $(BUILDDIR)/assets/json

NET_CLIMATEMPO_APP_$(REL).zip: buildall
    cd $(BUILDDIR); zip -r ../NET_CLIMATEMPO_APP_$(REL).zip .
```

Can anybody help me here?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Is the value of `$(BUILDDIR)` the `fubfolder` name you want in the zip file? (I assume not.) I doubt `zip` can fabricate a directory manually this way. You'll probably need to create a symlink directory with the name you want or something like that.

Comment: $(BUILDDIR) is the path for the folders I want to zip. I'm going to take a look about this symlink directory. tks!